# Serverless getting started demo errors on deploy

Tags: serverless-framework

I'm following the instructions for the serverless quickstart demo https://github.com/serverless/serverless-starter

and I'm getting an error on `serverless dash deploy`

What am I doing wrong - it seems like such a basic walkthrough.

```
Serverless: Deploying the specified functions in "dev" to the following regions: us-east-1  
/Users/bar/serverless-starter/node_modules/serverless-optimizer-plugin/index.js:266
              if (!result || !result.code) {
               ^
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed with my PR here:
https://github.com/serverless/serverless-optimizer-plugin/pull/41